# Cannot determine size of graphic in * (no BoundingBox)

Tags: conversion, eps, gif

I use `convert filename.gif filename.eps` to produce EPS from images before include them into TeX document, and get error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in filename.eps (no BoundingBox).
```

Environment: OpenSUSE 11.3 and oficial versions of texlive-latex and ImageMagick.

Comment: Hey Sannis, and welcome! Just a few pointers: We usually don't post "answers" posed as "questions", as the platform is not suitable for a forum-like discussion or a wiki, but rather functions as pure Q&A. If you have a specific question, we'd be more than happy to help. In the meantime, take a look at the FAQ: http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq to get some idea how TeX.SE works. Welcome again, and enjoy your stay!

Comment: I don't get this problem. If you do, maybe you have an old version of ImageMagick? Mine also lets me specify .eps as an extension.

Comment: @Harald: The problem seems to be when one is using `graphics` vs `graphicx`. I remember seeing this issue before, but I'm a bit fuzzy on the details.

Comment: I suppose there may be occasions where an unsolicited answer like this may be welcome. But then, it is better if the poster states the question as a question, then posts an answer to it immediately. It fits the overall structure of the site better, and besides it has the benefit that the answer won't be listed from now on until eternity as an unanswered question. In fact, I call on Sannis to do so: Just copy the bulk of your question into an answer box, submit as an answer, then go back and change the question.

Comment: I agree with Martin and Harald's sentiments.  There's nothing particularly wrong with using this place to share tips like this (though please don't flood the site with them all in one go!), but they should conform to the style of the site as a question-and-answer.  This will ensure that they are found correctly when someone is searching for them.

Comment: Thanks for you recommendations! I've split it into question and answer in proper way :)

Comment: @Harald, I use system all TeX components and ImageMagick from system repo and think that if they are very outdated, there are more reason to post this solution :) @Martin, I use graphicx, so it should be better that graphics, isn't it?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I agree, except for the _immediately_ part. A [discussion on meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away) said one should wait a bit before self-answering. (Kind of tardy comment, but anyways ...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use this little trick to solve this problem:

```
$> convert filename.gif filename.ps
$> ps2eps -f --fixps filename.ps
```

Comment: I am a little confused - this doesn't appear at all to have been a tip! it was clearly a question about why a certain procedure resulted in an error message with an implied question about how one might fix it. People who are really comfortable with UNIX/Linux manuals tend not to be so good in understanding language understood by the rest of us. But it is a little odd because the standard UNIX/Linux manuals tend to leave an awful lot of detail out, so one might think that the usual suspects would be better able to read between the lines than the average non UNIX/Linux manual reader.

Comment: @drtcbear As I understand it, the suggestion here is that `convert` will not get the bounding box correct if you go straight from `.gif` to `.eps`. So the work-around is to use `convert` to make a PostScript (`.ps`) file, then use `ps2eps` to convert this intermediate file to `.eps` format. Unlike `convert`, `ps2eps` should get the bounding box information right.

Comment: Don't know what drtcbear was talking about, this was the perfect solution for me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not totaly related but an awnser to the question:
I've had the same problem but it was caused by the fact that the name and the folder had a "dot" in the name thats why the pdflatex compiler couldnt find it.