# Creating standalone eps files and using batch files to automate the process

Tags: pdf, conversion, eps

I have been looking at these posts

[How to fix EPS with incorrect bounding box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22063/how-to-fix-eps-with-incorrect-bounding-box)

[Cannot determine size of graphic in * (no BoundingBox)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6852/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic-in-no-boundingbox)

[How to convert PDF to EPS?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps)

[How to produce EPS instead of PS using latex.exe followed by dvips?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/how-to-produce-eps-instead-of-ps-using-latex-exe-followed-by-dvips)

in order to understand how to create a standalone `pdf` from an `eps` figure and how to get an `eps` file also from an `eps` in which the `psfrag` labels have not yet been replaced. The above posts have been most useful.

My `eps` figures are usually done with Adobe Illustrator (AI) and then I use `psfrag` to replace whatever original labels in the AI figure to whatever I need with laTeX fonts. It works perfectly.

The issue with having such a workflow is that the original `eps` file from AI doesn't have the correct labels yet. This means that I cannot send someone this `eps` file from AI. Based on the above-mentioned posts, I have created a workflow that appears good to me in order to generate an independent `eps` file with all `psfrag` labels correctly inserted. My objective is to still have all fonts embedded in the final `eps` file. Here is my workflow with reference to the file `jeffcott.eps` that I have stored here:

http://petitlien.fr/epspicture

(A). Check the bounding box of jeffcott.eps

```
gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -sDEVICE=bbox jeffcott.eps
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 373 190
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000211 372.617989 189.934025
```

(B). Convert to standalone pdf

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage[hiresbb,dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\psfrag{A}{$m$}
\psfrag{B}{$k,c$}
\psfrag{Y}{inner stator bore}
\includegraphics{E:/jeffcott.eps}
\end{document}
```

(C). Create an `eps` file from the above resulting `pdf` file

```
pdfcrop --hires "standpdf.pdf" "standpdf-temp.pdf"
```

Next issue the `pdftops` command:

```
pdftops -level3 -eps standpdf-temp.pdf standpdf.eps
```

Now, `standpdf.eps` is created but Ghostscript warns that it cannot find its bbox. The problem is that the lines `%%BoundingBox` and `%%HiResBoundingBox` appear quite far away from the top header lines. I have two solutions:

I: Move these two lines corresponding to the bbox just after the first header line

II: Use `ps2eps`

```
ps2eps -f --fixps standpdf.eps
```

The file `standpdf.eps.eps` is created by `ps2eps` and Ghostscript can load the file without any complaint.

Checking the bbox gives:

```
 gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -sDEVICE=bbox standpdf.eps.eps
 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 373 190
 %%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000352 372.617989 189.935994
```

However when I open the file `standpdf.eps.eps` in a text editor, I can see the bbox as

```
 %%BoundingBox: 0 1 372 190
 %%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 1.000000 372.000000 190.000000
```

My questions:

1. As you can see from `part (c)` above, Ghostscript doesn't always read the correct bbox of the `eps` file. Why is this so?
2. Is it right to use the command `ps2eps` on an `eps` file. I have tried to use `epstool` but it seems that this tool can only copy a bbox from one file to another, and not fix it.
3. I would like to create a batch file on a `Windows` machine to automate the task in parts (B) and (C) and deleting the temporary file `standpdf-temp.pdf` along the way. I have looked at the batch files listed in some of the posts mentioned at the beginning of this post, but they do not work.
4. As a step further to `Question 3`, I would like to create a batch file that will process all the `pdf` files in a folder and create the corresponding `eps` files. How to do this?
5. And a related question: Where to learn about creating batch files for `Windows`? I haven't found any comprehensive source of information yet.

---

Update:

The batch files provided by xport work fine. There is one small bug however. Looking at `BatchF.bat`, after processing with `ps2eps`, the lines that come afterwards do not get processed at all. `Ps2eps` throws control back to the command prompt but the batch file stops there. How to fix that?

Since this post is getting long, I have created a new post:

[How to automate a job of changing tags in a bunch of EPS images and convert them to PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23555/batch-files-and-making-the-workflow-with-pdflatex-and-texlive-2010-easier-with-ps)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm so happy that Till Tantau created TikZ! I love `pdflatex` and the fact that I do not have these issues any longer.

Comment: "Ghostscript doesn't always read the correct bbox of the eps file" The `-sDEVICE=bbox` *calculates* the bounding box not reads them from the file, so it should be more correct.

Comment: The problem with gs complaining it can't find the bbox is an error in the eps from `pdftops -eps`. You can fix it by piping through `sed '2s/^/%/'` to double the `%` at the beginning of the second line.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be a bit clearer when you mention the piping part. How to achieve this on `windows`?

Comment: @yCall: see my update!

Comment: Thanks. A new problem in use of a batch file came up. See my post.

Comment: Re piping, I mean a command something like `pdftops -level3 -eps myfile.pdf - | sed '2s/^/%/' > myfile.eps`. I do this on windows using [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) but that is quite a big thing to setup only for access to `sed`, and there are presumably standalone versions of `sed` for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide you with 6 batch files. Each takes a (La)TeX input file name *without* extension. It will compile a single (La)TeX input file to produce an output in both PDF and EPS. In development phase, you may compile the same (La)TeX input file with each of the 6 batch files, and investigate which one suits you best. Each of the 6 batch files processes a single (La)TeX input file using different steps internally. The description will be clearer later in the next explanation.

In the production phase, you should have decided which one among them will be applied on a bunch of (La)TeX input files you have. Since applying the batch file on a bunch of (La)TeX input files is very tedious job, I provide you with an additional batch file to automate the process. Thus there are 7 batch files in total.

### BatchA.bat

```
rem batchA.bat
rem echo off
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
dvips -R -t unknown %1
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None -dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps %1-temp.pdf
pdfcrop --restricted --hires %1-temp %1.pdf
pdftops -level3 -eps %1.pdf
rem acrord32 %1.pdf
del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1.ps
del %1-temp.pdf
```

1. It can be used for an input file with any paper size.
2. Steps: `TEX -> DVI -> PDF -> cropping -> EPS`.
3. `pdfcrop` takes a significant amount of time to do cropping. If you don't need cropping, don't use this batch file.

### BatchB.bat

```
rem batchB.bat
echo off
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
dvips -R -t unknown %1
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None -dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps
pdftops -level3 -eps %1.pdf
rem acrord32 %1.pdf
del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1.ps
```

1. It can be used only for an input file with *tight* paper size.
2. Steps: `TEX -> DVI -> PDF -> EPS`.
3. It runs faster than `batchA.bat` because no cropping with `pdfcrop`. The drawback is you must specify the paper size tightly.

### BatchC.bat

```
rem batchC.bat
echo off
latex %1
dvips -t unknown %1
gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%1.pdf %1.ps
pdftops -eps %1.pdf
rem acrord32 %1.pdf
del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1.ps
```

1. It is almost the same as the `batchB.bat` but with fewer switches to speed up the compilation.
2. It can be used only for an input file with *tight* paper size.
3. Steps: `TEX -> DVI -> PDF -> EPS`.
4. It runs faster than `batchA.bat` because no cropping with `pdfcrop`. The drawback is you must specify the paper size tightly.

### BatchD.bat

```
rem batchD.bat
echo off
tex %1
dvips -t unknown %1
gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%1.pdf %1.ps
pdftops -eps %1.pdf
rem acrord32 %1.pdf
del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1.ps
```

1. It is almost the same as the `batchC.bat` but using `tex.exe` instead of `latex.exe`. The input file must be in plain TeX format. I hope it becomes faster than `methodC.bat`, but it has not been tested yet as I have many troubles to convert the input file from LaTeX to plain TeX. Benchmarking will be done soon.
2. It can be used only for an input file with *tight* paper size.
3. Steps: `TEX -> DVI -> PDF -> EPS`.
4. It runs faster than `batchA.bat` because no cropping with `pdfcrop`. The drawback is you must specify the paper size tightly.

### BatchE.bat

```
rem batchE.bat
rem echo off
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
dvips -R -t unknown -E %1 -o %1-temp.eps
epstool --copy --bbox %1-temp.eps %1.eps
epstopdf --hires %1.eps
rem acrord32 %1.pdf
del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1-temp.eps
```

1. It can be used for an input file with any paper size.
2. Steps: `TEX -> DVI -> EPS -> bounding box correction -> PDF`.
3. The file size of the resulting EPS is larger than that of one produced by each of the first 4 batch files (a,b,c,d).

### BatchF.bat

```
rem batchF.bat
echo off
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
dvips -R -t unknown %1 -o %1-temp.ps
ps2eps %1-temp.ps
epstool --copy --bbox %1-temp.eps %1.eps
epstopdf --hires %1.eps
rem acrord32 %1.pdf
del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1-temp.ps
del %1-temp.eps
```

1. It can be used for an input file with any paper size.
2. Steps: `TEX -> DVI -> PS -> EPS -> bounding box correction -> PDF`.
3. The file size of the resulting EPS is larger than that of one produced by each of the first four batch files (a,b,c,d).
4. I forgot the benchmark result when comparing `batchE.bat` and `batchF.bat`.

### Automate.bat

```
rem automate.bat
rem it takes a single character from {a,b,c,d,e,f}.
rem the options are case-insensitive.
rem for example: automate a
rem another example: automate F
echo off
for %%x in (*.tex) do batch%1.bat %%~nx
pause
```

If you have any problem, drop a comment.

---

Update in response to your misuse.

Each of {`batchA.bat`,`batchB.bat`,`batchC.bat`,`batchD.bat`,`batchE.bat`,`batchF.bat`} takes one input file name without extension. For example, if you want to use `batchE.bat` for `helloworld.tex`, then you must type `batchE helloworld` and hit enter.

If you want to use `batchE.bat` for a bunch of input files that exists in the same directory in which all batch files exist, then you type `automate E` and hit enter.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, place all batch files in the same directory in which your (La)TeX input files exist.

Comment: Be careful: My batch files above only accept file names without spaces. If your input file names contain spaces then encloses any file place holder in the batch with double quotes, for example: `"%1-temp.pdf"`.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive writing and help. I have run BatchA.bat but it doesn't work properly. I get some eps and pdf outputs but they are blank files. I have put the output up in my post so that you can see where things are going bad and possibly tell me what Im doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: @yCal: see my update!

Comment: Thanks. Yes I figured this out some hours afterwards when I read your answer again. So I have cleaned my post, taking away irrelevant info. I have another question about the `ps2eps` tool that makes any lines that come afterwards in the batch file useless. how to fix this? More in my post.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as you really have been most helpful. I have created a new post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23555/batch-files-and-making-the-workflow-with-pdflatex-and-texlive-2010-easier-with-ps as a continuation of this post. See my updated post up. And 1 vote up.

Answer (score 2):

Partially answered...
The remaining will be added later...

---

### How to create a batch file

Please skim the following example first and try to understand without reading my explanation that will follow.

```
rem this is a batch file named xport.bat
rem it need a single argument which is a name of TeX input file.
rem don't include the trailing .tex please! 
echo off
latex %1
dvips -t unknown %1
gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%1.pdf %1.ps
pdftops -eps %1.pdf
acrord32 %1.pdf
del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1.ps
rename %1.pdf xport.pdf
```

Explanation:

1. A batch file may take optional arguments. If you execute `xport.bat` with an argument as follows,

   ```
   xport mytexinputfilewithoutextension
   ```

   the `%1` will be set to `mytexinputfilewithoutextension`.
2. `rem` is a batch keyword to make a comment. It is analogous to `%` in TeX.
3. `echo off` is used not to display the syntax of command being executed.
4. `latex %1` stands for executing `latex` on `%1` file which is `myinputfilewithoutextension`. `latex` and `dvips` do not need file extension, but `gswin32c`, `pdftops` and `acrord32`, `del`, `rename` do need the file extension.
5. `del %1.log` is used to delete a file `%1.log`.
6. And `rename %1.pdf xport.pdf` is used to rename `%1.pdf` to `xport.pdf`.

Comment: Again: the correct language marker is `<!-- language: lang-none -->` with **no* space between `language` and the `:`. With the space it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One nice tool for such things is [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) which is a vector graphic editor but can also be run on the command line. It comes for Linux, Max and Windows. However, it uses additional software like Ghostscript by itself.

If you using it `-D` option then the file is groped down to the drawing. It can export EPS and PDF as well as SVG which is nice for websites.

The steps would be:

```bsh
latex file
dvips file
inkscape -D --export-eps file.eps file.ps
```

This gives me a nice groped EPS file from an A4 document with a single drawing in it. If you replace `--export-eps` with `--export-pdf` you get PDF output.

Comment: the eps export of inkscape is a lousy one ... Using `dvips` with the `-E` option and  `epstool` makes more sense.