# How to automate a job of changing tags in a bunch of EPS images and convert them to PDF

Tags: pdf, conversion, eps, psfrag

This post is a continuation to my earlier post here:

[Creating standalone eps files and using batch files to automate the process](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23362/creating-standalone-eps-files-and-using-batch-files-to-automate-the-process)

`Xport` gave good answers that work!

One goal of this whole process of automation also helps when using `pdfLaTeX` is used instead of the traditional `tex > dvi > ps > pdf` route. With `TeXLive 2010`, one can just issue the `pdfLaTeX` command and all `eps` files get converted on the fly to `pdf` and get inserted in the document.

I do not like the `pdfLaTeX` workflow but it compiles much faster than the traditional `tex > dvi > ps > pdf` route. So I have decided to use `pdfLaTeX` while a document is still work-in-progress and then I can use the workflow `tex > dvi > ps > pdf` to get the final compilation with all proper `eps` files inserted.

Now with `pdfLaTeX`, an `eps` file gets converted to `pdf` as follows:

e.g. `jeffcott.eps` gets converted to `jeffcott-eps-converted-to.pdf` and `model.eps` gets converted to `model-eps-converted-to.pdf`.

Making use of `Xport` batch files, I have tried to automate the above:

First we have the file `automate.bat` as follows:

```
for %%x in (*.tex) do dobatch.bat %%~nx
```

where the `dobatch.bat` is

```
 rem echo off
 latex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
 dvips -R -t unknown %1
 ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None -dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dEPSCrop %1.ps %1-temp.pdf
 pdfcrop --restricted --hires %1-temp %1.pdf
 rename %1.pdf %1-eps-converted-to.pdf
 pdftops -level3 -eps %1-eps-converted-to.pdf
 del %1.log
 del %1.aux
 del %1.dvi
 del %1.ps
 del %1-temp.pdf
 ps2eps -f --fixps %1-eps-converted-to.eps
 del %1.eps
```

Let's take an example to see what's happening:

Say I have the file `jeffcott.eps` and `model.eps` with unreplaced `psfrag` labels.

These files are here:

http://petitlien.fr/epspicture

I create the file `jeffcott.tex` working on `jeffcott.eps`as follows:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage[hiresbb,dvips]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[dvips]{color}
 \usepackage{psfrag}
 \usepackage{fourier}
 \newcommand{\figtext}{\small}
 \begin{document}
 {\figtext
 \psfrag{A}{$m$}
 \psfrag{B}{$k,c$}
 \psfrag{Y}{inner stator bore}
 \includegraphics{jeffcott.eps}}
 \end{document}
```

and a similar one `model.tex` working on `model.eps` as given below:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage[hiresbb,dvips]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[dvips]{color}
 \usepackage{psfrag}
 \usepackage{fourier}
 \newcommand{\figtext}{\small}
 \begin{document}
 {\figtext
 \psfrag{D}{$x$}
 \psfrag{E}{$y$}
 \psfrag{F}{$\omega_\mathrm{ro}$}
 \psfrag{G}{$\omega_\mathit{fo} \thinspace t$}
 \psfrag{H}{$\beta$}
 \psfrag{I}{$a$}
 \psfrag{J}{$r$}
 \psfrag{K}{$\theta$}
 \psfrag{L}{$r$}
 \psfrag{M}{$\mathrm{C}_\mathrm{st}$}
 \psfrag{N}{$\mathrm{C}_\mathrm{ro}$}
 \includegraphics{model.eps}}
 \end{document}
```

I place `jeffcott.tex`, `model.tex`, `automate.bat` and `dobatch.bat` in the same folder as `jeffcott.eps` and `model.eps`, and then I run `automate.bat`. The following files are now in that folder:

A. The original files

```
jeffcott.tex
model.tex
jeffcott.eps
model.eps
automate.bat
dobatch.bat
```

B. And the created files from running the `automate.bat`

```
jeffcott-eps-converted-to.eps
jeffcott-eps-converted-to.eps.eps
jeffcott-eps-converted-to.pdf

model-eps-converted-to.eps
model-eps-converted-to.eps.eps
model-eps-converted-to.pdf
```

I am close to what I need as `jeffcott-eps-converted-to.pdf` and `model-eps-converted-to.pdf` have been created. These are `pdf` files with all labels by `psfrag` inserted unlike those `pdf` files generated by running `pdflatex` with `TeXLive 2010` which would not contain the replaced labels. What I did in the file `dobatch.bat` was to make sure that I get the same filenames as those which would be created by `pdfLaTeX`. Now I can just replace the `pdfLaTeX` `pdf` versions of my original `eps` files with these `pdf` files created with the batch file.

I have four questions:

I. In the file `dobatch.bat`, there is the line: `ps2eps -f --fixps %1-eps-converted-to.eps`

whatever code comes after this line in the batch file get ignored. Why is that and how to fix that?

II. Ghostscript cannot read the bbox for `jeffcott-eps-converted-to.eps` and `model-eps-converted-to.eps`. This is why I use `ps2eps` to fix the bbox and it works. And I get the files: `jeffcott-eps-converted-to.eps.eps` and `model-eps-converted-to.eps.eps`. Since I have the original `eps` files: `jeffott.eps` and `model.eps` (without the `psfrag` labels) in the same directory, I would like to have the new correct `eps` files with all labels included named as `jefcottalone.eps` and `modelalone.eps` to emphasize that they stand alone. How to achieve this in th batch file `dobatch.bat`?

III. In my file `jeffcott.tex`, I have used the line:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
```

Does the `standalone` package accept the option `12pt`? I did not see this in the manual.

IV. In my file `jeffcott.tex`, I use the command:

```
\newcommand{\figtext}{\small}
```

to specify whatever text in the figure should be of size `\figtext`. It seems to work. Is this the correct way of doing things?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my post and put the tags. See the listings of `jeffcott.tex` and `model.tex` in my post for which `psfrag` labels that are involved.

Comment: I get the impression that `pdfLateX` does run faster. Perhaps because `eps` files are usually larger than the corresponding `pdf` files. Anyway if this is not true, the post here is helping a lot for me to understand `eps` files better and create standalone `eps` and `pdf`files.

Comment: So you mean that I can just take away the `stanadalone`class and use a normal `article` class here? Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to tidy up your question above, make it a bit shorter but still reflects the essence. I don't know who had down voted your question above, it might be because he/she felt confused when reading it. Thank you. Please also remove your unnecessary comments. I have done it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scenario:

Please confirm, whether or not your situation like below.

1. You have a bunch of EPS files.
2. You want to replace some certain tags on each EPS. To do so, you have prepared files `file01.tex` for `image01.eps`, `file01.tex` for `image02.eps`, etc. For example, you have prepared `file01.tex` and `file02.tex` as follow:

   ```
   % file01.tex for image01.eps
   \documentclass[dvips]{article}
   \pagestyle{empty}
   \parindent=0pt
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{psfrag}

   \begin{document} 
   \small
   \psfrag{a}{$A$}
   \psfrag{b}{$B$}
   \psfrag{c}{I am C!}
   \includegraphics{image01}
   \end{document}
   ```

   ```
   % file02.tex for image02.eps
   \documentclass[dvips]{article}
   \pagestyle{empty}
   \parindent=0pt
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{psfrag}

   \begin{document} 
   \small
   \psfrag{G}{\color{red}$m$}
   \psfrag{H}{\color{red}$k,c$}
   \psfrag{I}{\color{red}inner stator bore}
   \includegraphics{image02}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. You want to automate the process to produce a PDF version for each of EPS.
4. All white spaces surrounding the valuable object in EPS must be
   trimmed in PDF.
5. You want to import the resulting PDF files to your main document such as thesis, article, etc.

If it is your real scenario, then I will give you the correct direction. I am confused with your lengthy question.

### Solution:

The following is the workflow you must do.

1. Create a batch file for compiling a single `file**.tex` to produce `file**.pdf`. Name the batch file `EpsToPdf.bat` as follows.

   ```
   rem EpsToPdf.bat
   rem It takes a file name without extension.
   rem For example: EpsToPdf file01
   rem Another example: EpsToPdf file02

   latex "%1"
   dvips -t unknown "%1"
   ps2pdf "%1.ps" "%1-temp.pdf"
   pdfcrop --hires "%1-temp" "%1.pdf"
   rem acrord32 "%1.pdf"
   del "%1.log"
   del "%1.aux"
   del "%1.dvi"
   del "%1.ps"
   del "%1-temp.pdf"
   ```
2. Create another batch file to automate the process of compiling all `file**.tex`. Name this batch `automate.bat` as follows.

   ```
   rem automatic.bat
   rem just execute without any switch.
   for %%x in (*.tex) do EpsToPdf.bat "%%~nx"
   ```
3. Make sure all `image**.eps`, `file**.tex`, batch files are in the same directory. This is needed unless you have set the `PATH` environment variable to the path pointing to the batch files.
4. Execute `automatic.bat` by double clicking it. Wait until all PDF are generated. If there are missing PDF, then check the corresponding `file**.tex`.
5. To import the resulting PDF to your main document such as thesis, article, journal, etc, create another TeX document as follow. It is just a trivial example.

   ```
   % main.tex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
   \begin{document}
   \lipsum[1]
   \includegraphics{file01}

   \lipsum[2]
   \includegraphics{file02}
   \end{document}
   ```

   And compile it using the following batch file, just type `TexToPdf main` and hit enter in DOS-prompt.

   ```
   rem TexToPdf.bat
   rem It takes a file name without extension.
   rem For example: TexToPdf main

   pdflatex "%1"
   pdflatex "%1"
   rem acrord32 "%1.pdf"
   del "%1.log"
   del "%1.aux"
   rem del "%1.***" <=== change *** to something meaningful
   ```

   `pdflatex.exe` are intentionally executed twice to get correct cross-references.
6. Done!

### Additional:

If you need EPS output as well, then you must insert `pdftops -eps "%1.pdf"` right after `pdfcrop --hires "%1-temp" "%1.pdf"` in `EpsToPdf.bat` above.

But be careful !!!! Read the following carefully !!!

> If your TeX input file has the same name as the imported EPS file has, then
>   the original EPS file will be overwritten. You will lose the original EPS!
>   To avoid this, you must not give the TeX input file a name that is
>   equal to the name of the original EPS.

Comment: Yes it's ok. I don't understand your point `4` though, but this doesn't seem to be a big issue. And I would like to have a standalone `eps` as well with all the `psfrag` labels inserted. This standalone `eps` should not be a raster image. Thanks.

Comment: So my goal is to have both standalone `pdf` and `eps` files.

Comment: As I pointed out before, any commands in the batch files that comes after `ps2eps` do not get processed at all. So all the `del` commands that you had in your batch file after the line `ps2eps` do not get processed.

Comment: Thanks. I need an EPS file if I need to send someone a standalone EPS figure. For example, journals at times prefer to have standalone EPS figures to work with rather than having to run the PSFRAG command in the LaTeX files.

Comment: With the ps2pdf, maybe the setting -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress can be useful.