# Converting EPS file to standalone PDF with PSFRAGs or compiling both data types in one Latex file

Tags: pdftex, pdf, eps, psfrag

I have a few figure files and some of them are already PDF files, for example directly obtained from MATLAB as PDF standalone file. Some 3 or 4 files are EPS files with which I use PSFRAG to embed the nice fonts. I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to compile both types of files in one latex application? I have pdflatex and dvi-ps-pdf., where the former needs all PDF files and the latter accepts only EPS files.
2. How to obtain a standalone PDF file from an EPs file with embedded fonts with PSFRAG.

About the second question, will it give exactly the same result (quality) as I usually get with the triple dvi-ps-pdf?

I had a look at this question:

[Creating standalone eps files and using batch files to automate the process](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23362/creating-standalone-eps-files-and-using-batch-files-to-automate-the-process/23390#23390)

which suggests this code

->Convert to standalone pdf

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage[hiresbb,dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\psfrag{A}{$m$}
\psfrag{B}{$k,c$}
\psfrag{Y}{inner stator bore}
\includegraphics{E:/jeffcott.eps}
\end{document}
```

I tried this code but I got an error: It says "no bounding box" and "can not determine the size of graphic".

The same question gives something related to that in his answers part B. But I did not understand it. Could someone help me about the issue?

Comment: Do you know about [`epstopdf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) script and companion package?

Comment: @PaulGessler In the linux machine I think I can use it as I used the otherway around pdftoeps. But I dont know the details. I mean \psfrag{u12}[t][]{$\phi_{12}$}
\psfrag{u21}[t][]{\hspace{2mm}$\phi_{21}$}
\psfrag{ph}{\hspace{-8mm}Phi} If epstopdf could understand these arguments.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @MartinSchröder thanks for the explanation. I do both ways, anyways.